# How to set download pdf option in each row in REACT GRID TABLE

Tags: reactjs

I am using React Grid table and there I want to add another column to download the pdf of each row. how to set link  for every row of one column.

```
  const [columns] = useState([
  
     {
       name: "Download", title: 'Report',
       Cell: e =><a href={e.value}> {e.value} </a>
      // Cell: e =><a href= "#" onClick={()=>downloadPdf()}></a>
     },
  ]);
```

actually here I trying to set a link in each row, but am getting the empty column for the report.

Comment: add a snapshot of your code !

Comment: Add your code to your question.